# Execute Command After Previous one Finished

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Is there a terminal emulator which allows the user to execute a command after the one currently running terminates?

I'm searching for a software, not for an explanation of how to concatenate commands (for example via `&&` or `;`). It's just that I often want to do something after something else finished but don't plan everything ahead. A small context menu entry called "execute after current command finished" opening a new terminal window which does exactly that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a Bash CLI. There are at least two ways to do this, depending on how much you do want to plan ahead.

If you type a command and <kbd>enter</kbd>, and then decide you want to run some other command when that finishes, you can do this:

```
001 $ date; sleep 10
002 Mon, Jan 25, 2016  3:08:35 PM
003 tty; date
004 $ tty; date
005 /dev/pty2
006 Mon, Jan 25, 2016  3:08:45 PM
```

Notes:

- Line numbers ("001 ...") are added
- Line 001: two commands run sequentially due to <kbd>;</kbd>, second one is long-running
- Line 002: the immediate output from 'date' on line 001, for reference
- Line 003: User types additional commands while the 'sleep' command from line 001 is still running, the typing is echoed but is not interpreted until 'sleep' completes
- Line 004: <kbd>$</kbd> prompt appears marking end execution of second command on line 001, rest is re-echo of line 003.
- Line 005: Output of 'tty' command entered at line 003
- Line 006: Output of 'date' command entered at line 003, compare to line 002

However, if you know in advance that you will want to start something else after an initial command, but you don't know what yet, you can wait for it explicitly as:

```
006 $ date; sleep 20 &
007 Mon, Jan 25, 2016  3:13:52 PM
008 [1] 504840
009 $ wait 504840; tty; date
010 [1]+  Done                    sleep 20
011 /dev/pty2
012 Mon, Jan 25, 2016  3:14:12 PM
```

Notes:

- Line 006: 'date' for reference, and then the 'sleep' command is pushed to the background with final <kbd>&</kbd>
- Line 007: output of 'date' on line 006, for reference
- Line 008: output of <kbd>&</kbd> on line 006, giving PID of 'sleep' command
- Line 009: 'wait' will wait for process with named PID to complete
- Line 010: 'sleep' on line 006 completes, then 'tty; date' will be interpreted
- Line 011: output of 'tty' on line 009
- Line 012: output of 'date' on line 009, compare to line 007

Answer (score 0):

You can type or paste your new command in the shell window where the current command is being executed and the shell will see it and execute it after the current command finishes.

No additional menu entry needed.

E.g.:

```
$ command1
command2
$ $
```

(the repeated prompt is printed because the shell will prompt you after executing `command1` before starting `command2`).

Note that if you kill `command1` with [`kill`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)), then `command2` is executed right away, but if you type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in this shell, this will abort *both* commands.